# await blocks the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have an action in my controller in which there is an `async` function call

```
 public  async Task<ActionResult> Subscribe(AspNetUser user, string newUploadPath)
 {
    //do some work
    await DocServiceImpl.CopyUserAllModels(user, newUploadPath);
    //do some work
    return RedirectToAction("List", "ClientDashboard");
 }
```

and this function uploads a lot of files to `Azure CDN` so it takes too long.

The problem is that the client who makes this request has to wait until the `CopyUserAllModels` function finishes, because all this waiting time the client sees his page is reloading in the browser.

I've tried not to wait at all and used without `await`

```
DocServiceImpl.CopyUserAllModels(user, newUploadPath);
```

but I've searched that this is a bad experience, and except it, 
in this case I find that some part of the files haven't been uploaded at all, so 
without `await` it does not work properly in my case(I couldn't understand why).

My problem is: How to finish the request earlier, and then after it do all the work in `CopyUserAllModels` function?

Comment: `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`?

Comment: I've just read a little  about `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` and it looks like what I want. Thanks.